# Best practice/Style for importing font into angular 4 cli web application

Tags: html, css, angular, fonts

I have been working on an Angular 4 personal project, and wanted to add the Ubuntu font family to my Angular application. What is the best practice or style for adding a number of custom fonts to a project? I currently have saved the ubuntu font family into /assets/fonts/ubuntu-font-family-0.83 and added it to the outer most component CSS file, app.component.css with font face.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu';
   src: url('/assets/fonts/ubuntu-font-family-0.83/Ubuntu-R.ttf');
}
```

By putting this in the original component I don't have to redefine the font in nested components i just treat it like a default font-family.

Is there a clearer/better way to do this and still cut out duplicate code?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is better way to include fonts to the website, not only to angular app.

Checkout https://fonts.google.com

Why it is better?

- higher performance
- higher chance, that your customer will have font in his cache
- you don't have to worry about attaching files, and use yours origin bandwidth

In your case you would import following in your css file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');
```

You can place it in the main .css file, included by index.html. Or you can use `<link>` tag and include fonts in your headers (also in index.html)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you for you're response!  A couple other questions I have are: what CSS file would I put the import in? Would it be bad practice to include in every CSS file? And lastly, after importing do I just reference the font like I would normally `font-family: Ubuntu;` or do I have to declare a `@font-face`?

Comment: Thank you for providing reasons as to why the this method is better!

Comment: You don't need include to every CSS file. Include just in your top-level file. Yes, after defining font you can use it in other style sheets (just font-family: Ubuntu)

Comment: What about async loading?

Comment: You won't be able to reach users in China at present with that solution. Google APIs aren't accessible there. You could resolve that by using one of the sites that mirror fonts.googleapis.com such as https://notabug.org/mirror/google-fonts

Comment: This method is now risky in Europe due being questionable with regards to GDPR.

Comment: @JanPapenbrock seriously? Downloading font is against GDPR?

Comment: @MaciejTreder well, at least unclear: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/1495 We switched to hosting the fonts locally, just to be safe.

Comment: @JanPapenbrock As far as I can see this issue is closed :)

Comment: For me google fonts is taking too much time to load, hence I can see a browser repaint effect very clearly and making my website bad.

Comment: There are two reasons that make this solution problematic: 
1. As mentioned above google does not only serve the fonts but also collects data in the process which might collide with the local laws. 
2. You cannot access the fonts in an offline environment (for example in an intranet) with that solution.

Comment: This is in many cases **not** a better solution to serving your own fonts, and certainly not in the "best practice" category. What to do here goes in the "it depends" category. This solution is often the poorer choice, Including when cookies are rejected due to GDPR (and other country/state regulations) and the fact that google fonts are not necessarily performant. It's a free service, you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 9):

**This is best way to use google font locally with angular 2,4,5,6,7 and more**, First Download Google Font and add this inside the assets folder and use it is as per your requirement.

In angular.json call this in src/assets

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],
```

In css file add this font-face in top

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  src: url(/assets/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-weight:300;
}
```

At Last use it as per your requirement like

```
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```