# Angular 7 and CDNs

Tags: angular, cdn, angular7

I am writing my first Angular app using Angular 7.

Usually, when writing HTML I make use of CDNs for Bootstrap, fonts etc.

Looking at some tutorials they recommend leaving the default 'index.html' as generated but that seems to be the obvious place to add the CDNs for standard css, js and fonts.

Does Angular have another way of adding the CDNs.

Comment: You're still able to add CDNs like Bootstrap to the index.html file. The added scripts and stylesheets in the index.html file will be retained when the final build is generated.

Comment: For the custom scripts and styles you can import them using `angular-cli.json` within `styles: []` and `scripts: []` For fonts take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878591/best-practice-style-for-importing-font-into-angular-4-cli-web-application/44879077

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use CDNs then `index.html` is the place to do it.

However, the more common approach is to `npm install` the lib you want to use and then load it from the node_modules folder using `angular.json`

So, for example, to use bootstrap CSS this way:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Then in angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
]
```

Then restart your server. All the bootstrap styles will be bundled up in your app and accessible from any component.

Note in `angular.json` there are 2 `styles` array, you want the first one.

When you want to update to a newer version of bootstrap, just `npm install` the newer version.

The benefit of using node_modules is (1) accessing a resource locally is faster than accessing a resource from the internet (2) once node_modules are installed your app no longer relies on an internet connection to grab the resource.

Comment: While this is all true, serving fonts and 3rd party CSS from node_modules has some disadvantages: 1) makes your final bundles app size much larger 2) in production, it is always served from your server. Chances are the client has already downloaded some commonly used fonts and has them in cache without the need to re-download them

Answer (score 4):

You can include CDN in index.html file and another way of including this files is:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Then include this in scripts of your angular.json file

```
scripts [
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Then re-run your app and build your server.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply suggest to use [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duumze). They implement the on-the-fly approach to code and run Angular application without the need to have it running locally.

Comment: See @danday74 answer below for a much more precise explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way of using the alternative of CDN is to use npm install command and it will 
 provide you the functionality better and faster than cdn & also fix your angular-json file.

npm install bootstrap --save