# Angular assets static files not found

Tags: css, angular, nginx, fonts, static-files

Problem:
Resolving fonts which are inside assets folder results 404 Not Found error.
`http://server.com/assets/fonts/Bold/RobotoCondensed-Bold.woff2`

It work though on local development:
`http://localhost/assets/fonts/Bold/RobotoCondensed-Bold.woff2`

Details:
I have got some fonts which are inside assets folder.
They are correctly copied to docker image path: `/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/fonts/Bold/RobotoCondensed-Bold.woff2`

If I request `http://server.com/service/assets/fonts/Bold/RobotoCondensed-Bold.woff2`
then my font is retrieved. `/service` prefix is example name of which service is served.

Base href changes on local dev from `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/service/">` on server.com

How should I fix this problem. I could try changing url from `/assets/fonts/Light/RobotoCondensed-Light.woff` to `service/assets/fonts/Light/RobotoCondensed-Light.woff` but during local development this prefix does not exist so i my fonts would stop working on local environment.

Also I want to mention that my favicon.ico is correctly served.
On local environment front asks without prefix and on server it requests favicon with prefix /service. Favicon is only mentioned inside `index.html`:

`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

_fonts.scss file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Light/RobotoCondensed-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/assets/fonts/Light/RobotoCondensed-Light.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

angular.json file:

```
"assets": [
    "projects/service/src/favicon.ico",
    "projects/service/src/assets"
],
"styles": [
    "projects/service/src/assets/scss/modules/_fonts.scss"
],
```

I am pretty new to angular and frontend and cannot solve this issue.
Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878591/best-practice-style-for-importing-font-into-angular-4-cli-web-application/44879077

Comment: It was working with font from CDN, but now i need to have it served in offline scenerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use relative path in my urls
ex.

```
./assets/fonts/Light/RobotoCondensed-Light.woff
```